# Is there a penalty for dying In Cross Code?

Tags: cross-code

In my pursuit of S-rank combat rewards, I've gotten myself killed fighting a few more enemies than I can handle. I notice that when I die, combat resets and all enemies on the current map/screen respawn, but there doesn't seem to be any other cost that I can see.

Is there a penalty to dying that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the developer, there is no penalty for death other than progress made in the combat you died in [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/368340/discussions/0/154644705025824821/#c154644705027868298):

> When you die during a combat rank you only use the progress you made on the most recent map for both items and EXP.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried it out, and [Vemonus's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/296723/241432) is partially wrong, although their quote about what the developer said seems right.

Here's what I did:

1. I went to the "Entrance" room of "Bergen Trail", then I noted my experience amount (about 701/1000 (I was level 13 at that time)).
2. I started a combat rank: I killed a single mob (a bunny in this case, which gave me +22 experience).
3. I walked to the "Rising Path 1" room of "Bergen Trail" and came back right after (to the "Entrance" room), so that the game knew I changed room, but left the combat ranked mode active.
4. I let a mob kill me (still in combat rank, so I would expect to lose any progress).

However, when I respawned, my experience amount was higher (it had changed to 723/1000 (which is my initial experience amount +22)): There was *no penalty*.

In other words, when you die, you come back **exactly to the first place you've been at** in the current room, with the experience amount and the items you had at that moment.

So that's a little bit awkward because you can actually exploit this glitch to partially save progress while in combat rank...